# ::-webkit-inner-spin-button shows on Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox, input, spinner

I am trying to hide the spin buttons on numeric inputs, but the CSS below doesn't work anymore on Firefox 47 and 48.  Is there a solution?

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::-webkit-inner-spin-button

```css
input::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
}
```

```html
<input type="number">
```

Here is the spinner still showing in my Firefox 48 browser:
[image: spinner showing]

Comment: I solved creating my own spinner.

Answer (score 5):

For firefox

```
input[type="number"] { -moz-appearance: textfield; }
```

Answer (score 1):

I create my own spinner, based in others.

CSS

```
    input[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button,
    input[type=number]::-webkit-outer-spin-button {
       appearance: none;
      -webkit-appearance: none;
      -moz-appearance: none;
    margin: 0;
   }

   input[type=number] {
      -moz-appearance: textfield;
   }
```

CSS for my warper

```
    .spinnerwarpper {
        display: flex;
    }

    .spinnerwarpper input {
        width: calc(100% - 4em);
    }

    .spinnerwarpper i {
        padding: 0;
        padding-left: 0.1em;
        padding-top: 0.2em;
        white-space: nowrap;
        vertical-align: text-bottom;
        cursor: pointer;
        cursor: hand;
        color: #737373;
    }
```

JS for my warper

```
    function fjrSpinner(id) {
        org_html = document.getElementById(id).outerHTML;   
        new_html = "<section class='spinnerwarpper'>" + org_html;
        new_html = new_html + "<i class='fa fa-arrow-down fa-2x align-center numberdown"+id+" special' aria-hidden='true'></i>"
        new_html = new_html + "<i class='fa fa-arrow-up fa-2x align-center numberup" + id + "  special' aria-hidden='true'></i>"
        new_html = new_html + "</section>";
        document.getElementById(id).outerHTML = new_html;

        $('.numberup'+id).click(function (i, oldval) {
            var x = $(this).siblings('input')[0];
            var thisvalue = parseInt(x.value);
            var thismax = parseInt(x.max);
            if (!isNaN(thismax)){           
                if (thismax > thisvalue) {
                    thisvalue++;
                    x.value = thisvalue;
                } else {
                    x.value = thismax;
                }
            } else {
                thisvalue++;
                x.value = thisvalue;
            }
            //para ativar efeito do blur para  poder colocar um evento
            $('#' + id).trigger("blur");
        });
        $('.numberdown'+id).click(function (i, oldval) {
            var x = $(this).siblings('input')[0];
            var thisvalue = parseInt(x.value);
            var thismin = parseInt(x.min);
            if (!isNaN(thismin)) {
                if (thismin < thisvalue) {
                    thisvalue--;
                    x.value = thisvalue;
                } else {
                    x.value = thismin;
                }
            } else {
                thisvalue--;
                x.value = thisvalue;
            }
            //para ativar efeito do blur para  poder colocar um evento
            $('#'+id).trigger("blur");
        });

        org_html = document.getElementById(id);
        inputTypeNumberPolyfill.polyfillElement(org_html);
    };
```

And Polyfill script.